# Is it possible to evaluate and train a neural network based on many outputs as a group instead of evaluating one by one?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I was wondering if it was possible for a neural network to be trained by a group of outputs it gives, instead of each single output.

For example, as far as I know, if you want to build a neural network that plays a tic-tac-toe game, you would have to train it in a way that it knows what is the best possible move, but without human input of what are the best board states, how would it be possible for the neural network to 'learn' what the best move is?

This made me wonder if there is a way to train a neural network based on its results rather than each output, say, neural network gets the 1st turn, I ask it for an output to know its move, then its my turn and so on, I want to know if it's possible to train this neural network based on the result of the game, since I can't really tell if a move is "bad" or "good" until the end of the game, and to get to the end of the game I require atleast 3 outputs.

Is it possible to solve this with a neural network or am I looking for answers in the wrong technology?

Comment: Google for reinforcement learning and the credit assignment problem. This is more an outer layer  for NNs

Comment: You let it play against itself, and consider a "won game" as good, and a lost game as bad. once over 1mil games or a few days of training, it should be decent enough to challenge a human player. Somewhat simple case of reinforcement learning.

Comment: Ah then reinforcement learning is what i really needed to look for, Thanks!